# Undefined Method when using current_user from Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have just started using device. I set up everything according to the instructions: 1.  Defined default url options in your environment files, 2.Set the routes 3. Inserted flash messages 4. Generated the views and user model.

Sign up / Sign in etc. is working fine but when using the current_user helper from devise inside my controller like this (submissions_controller.rb):

```
   ...
   before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]
   ...

  def new
    @submit = current_user.Submit.new
    respond_with(@submit)
  end



  def create
    @submit = current_user.Submit.new(submit_params)
    @submit.save
    respond_with(@submit)
  end
```

I am getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError in SubmitsController#new
undefined method `Submit' for #<User:0x007fea99a46f38>

Extracted source (around line #18):

  def new
    @submit = current_user.Submit.new
    respond_with(@submit)
  end
```

Any ideas what might cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's the association between `User` and `Submit`, so

if user has many submits then change `current_user.Submit.new` to

```
current_user.submits.new
```

else if user has one submit

```
current_user.build_submit
```

Now using the above changes in your `new` and `create` actions

```
def new
  @submit = current_user.submits.new
  respond_with(@submit)
end

def create
  @submit = current_user.submits.new(submit_params)
  @submit.save
  respond_with(@submit)
end
```

and your submit_params should look like

```
def submit_params 
  params.require(:submit).permit(:title, :url) 
end
```

`require(:submit)` is correct

Hope it hepls!

Comment: thanks for your answer, rally appreciate it. The connection is user `has_many :submits`, submit `belongs_to :user`. With your suggestion I got rid of the error but now I am facing the following error:`param is missing or the value is empty: submit` in the following code `def submit_params
      params.require(:submit).permit(:title, :url)
    end` Any idea what this could be? I tried changing the code to `require(:submits)`already. Thanks again

Comment: That did the job! Thank you very much. Could you explain why the submit_params should not be passed into the def new? I had the code from a tutorial that showed it in this way...

Answer (score 0):

You have this line of code

```
@submit = current_user.Submit.new(submit_params)
```

It is failing here, because you are calling `Submit` method on `user` object, and you do not have `Submit` method. By looking at your code I see you wanted to create new `Submit`.

You should write

```
@submit = Submit.new(submit_params) # instantiate new Submit object
```